# defining operator doesn't work anymore (Error in UseMethod("%op%"): no applicable method for '%op%' applied to an object of class "character")

Tags: r

In my toy package, I have defined `%+%` operator as an alias to `paste0()`. Trying to reduce interference with other packages, I realized it the following way:

```
`%+%` <- function(...) UseMethod("%+%")

`%+%.character` <- paste0

`%+%.numeric` <- paste0

`%+%.default` <- function (arg1, arg2){
  e <- parent.env(getEnvByName(.GlobalEnv,'package:mypackagename'));
  if (exists('%+%', envir = e)) get('%+%',envir = e)(arg1,arg2);
}
```

i.e. I override it only for `character` and `numeric` arguments, otherwise it tries to find if the method was previously defined.
It was working just fine until recently when it started giving an error:

```
'a' %+% 'b'
# Error in UseMethod("%+%") : 
#  no applicable method for '%+%' applied to an object of class "character"
```

It only fails when called outside of the package. If I define a function within the package, it works correctly:

```
# testab2() is defined in R file as a part of the package:
testab2 <- function(inpA, inpB){
  print (inpA %+% inpB)
}


# when called outside of the package:
testab2('a','b')
# ab
```

I am pretty sure I didn't change anything in my code, so I'm wondering if it could be caused by R update. What could have changed and how to make it work back?

P.S. `getEnvByName()` is my helper function that searches for an object in parent environments:

```
getEnvByName <- function(inpEnv=.GlobalEnv, lookFor){
  e <- inpEnv;
  while (environmentName(e) != 'R_EmptyEnv' & environmentName(e)!=lookFor) e <- parent.env(e);
  if (environmentName(e) != lookFor) return(NULL);
  return(e);
}
```

And the exporting was done by the following lines in the `NAMESPACE` file:

```
exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")
exportPattern("%.*%")
export("%+%.default")
export("%+%.character")
```

P.P.S. sessionInfo:

```
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    
system code page: 1251

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] vautils_0.1.1.105 magrittr_1.5      data.table_1.13.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] dplyr_1.0.2      crayon_1.3.4     grid_4.0.2       R6_2.4.1         lifecycle_0.2.0  gtable_0.3.0    
 [7] scales_1.1.1     ggplot2_3.3.2    pillar_1.4.6     rlang_0.4.7      rstudioapi_0.11  generics_0.0.2  
[13] vctrs_0.3.4      ellipsis_0.3.1   tools_4.0.2      glue_1.4.2       purrr_0.3.4      munsell_0.5.0   
[19] compiler_4.0.2   pkgconfig_2.0.3  colorspace_1.4-1 tidyselect_1.1.0 tibble_3.0.3
```

Comment: Does the code fail *inside* your package, or outside when using the package. If the latter, how are you exporting your operator?

Comment: I don’t understand your default method: why not just use `e <- parent.env(topenv())`? Likewise, your (now unnecessary) `getEnvByName` could be replaced by `as.environment`.

Comment: it only fails outside. I export by adding lines like `export("%+%.default")` and `export("%+%.character")` in the `NAMESPACE` file.

Comment: Please add this information to the question, since that’s the crucial bit. Anyway, this isn’t how S3 methods should be exported, and is *probably* what causes the failure in new versions of R, though I’m not entirely sure.

Comment: as for the `parent.env(topenv())` - I remember having some issues, that's why I had to add my helper function. Can't remember the details, will try it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To export S3 methods, your `NAMESPACE` file needs to (in your case) contain the following declarations:

```r
export(`%+%`)
S3method(`%+%`, default)
S3method(`%+%`, character)
S3method(`%+%`, numeric)
```

That is, export the `%+%` generic, and [declare S3 methods for the methods](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Registering-S3-methods).

Better yet, instead of manually editing the `NAMESPACE` file use ‘roxygen2’, which generates the correct declarations for you [based on the `@export` documentation tag](https://roxygen2.r-lib.org/articles/namespace.html#exports).